# Web-приложение для определения заполненных форм

Tags: python, django

В базе данных хранится список шаблонов форм.

Шаблон формы, это структура, которая задается уникальным набором полей, с указанием их типов.

Пример шаблона формы:

```
{
    "name": "Form template name",
    "field_name_1": "email",
    "field_name_2": "phone" }
```

Всего должно поддерживаться четыре типа данных полей:

1. email
2. телефон
3. дата
4. текст

Все типы кроме текста должны поддерживать валидацию. Телефон передается в стандартном формате +7 xxx xxx xx xx, дата передается в формате DD.MM.YYYY или YYYY-MM-DD.

Имя шаблона формы задается в свободной форме, например MyForm или Order Form.
Имена полей также задаются в свободной форме (желательно осмысленно), например user_name, order_date или lead_email.

На вход по урлу /get_form POST запросом передаются данные такого вида:
f_name1=value1&f_name2=value2

В ответ нужно вернуть имя шаблона формы, если она была найдена.
Чтобы найти подходящий шаблон нужно выбрать тот, поля которого совпали с полями в присланной форме. Совпадающими считаются поля, у которых совпали имя и тип значения. Полей в пришедшей форме может быть больше чем в шаблоне, в этом случае шаблон все равно будет считаться подходящим. Самое главное, чтобы все поля шаблона присутствовали в форме.
Я использую Python Django.
**мой models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Название шаблона')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Шаблон'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Шаблоны'

class Field(models.Model):
    class Type:
        choices = (
                 ('email', "email"),
                 ('date', "date"),
                 ('phone', "phone"),
                 ('text', "text"),
             )
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, related_name='sample', verbose_name='Шаблон', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_field = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Имя поля')
    type_field = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=Type.choices, verbose_name='Тип поля')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_field

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Поле'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Поля'
```

**мой view.py**

```
from .utils import type_form
import json
# Create your views here.

class Templates_views (View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = type_form(request.GET)
        for k, v in form.items():
            s = Field.objects.filter(name_field=k, type_field=v)
            print(s.values_list())

        return JsonResponse(form)
```

**мой utils.py**

```
def type_v(v):
    test = {'email': r'^\S+@\w+.\w{2,4}$',
            'date': r'^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}$',
            'phone': r'^79\s*\d{2}\s*\d{3}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}$',
            }
    for t, r in test.items():
        if re.fullmatch(r, v):
            return t

    return 'text'


def type_form(d):
    res = {}
    d = d.dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        res[k] = type_v(v)
    retur
```

Из utils.py прилетает словарь вида

```
{
    "User_name": "text",
    "User_email": "email",
    "date": "date",
    "User_phone": "phone"
}
```

как правильно сделать поиск по данному словарю?

*Данные хранятся в моделях таком виде:*

````
```{"name": "User",
     "sample": [
            {
                "name_field": "User_name",
                "type_field": "text"
            },
            {
                "name_field": "User_email",
                "type_field": "email"
            },
            {
                "name_field": "User_phone",
                "type_field": "phone"
            }
        ]
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

> как правильно сделать поиск по данному словарю?

> В ответ нужно вернуть имя шаблона формы, если она была найдена. Чтобы найти подходящий шаблон нужно выбрать тот, поля которого совпали с полями в присланной форме. Совпадающими считаются поля, у которых совпали имя и тип значения

```py
form_fields_types = form_type(request.GET)

form_search_cond = Q()  # django.db.models.Q
for k, v in form_fields_types.items():
    form_search_cond &= Q(**{f'sample__{k}': v})

template = Template.objects.filter(form_search_cond)
```

Как-то так

---

PS: Собираете части условий поиска в одно, затем ищете

---

UPD:

```
form_search_cond.add(Q(sample__name_field=k) & Q(sample__type_field=v), Q.AND)
```

В моем примере нет `.add`. Если `form_search_cond` - объект `Q`, то мой вариант должен работать.

Если возникают ошибки, пишите какие именное ошибки

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку сделал         for k, v in form_fields_types.items():
            form_search_cond &= Q(**{'sample__name_field': k}, **{f'sample__type_field': v}). Но всё ровное не могу найти нормально

Comment: можете привести пример данных в моделях?

Comment: Дописал в теле вопроса                                                                                                       
 ```{"name": "User",
     "sample": [
            {
                "name_field": "User_name",
                "type_field": "text"
            },
            {
                "name_field": "User_email",
                "type_field": "email"
            },
            {
                "name_field": "User_phone",
                "type_field": "phone"
            }
        ]
    }
    ```

Comment: Я сделал следующее, но оно не работает form_search_cond.add(Q(sample__name_field=k) & Q(sample__type_field=v), Q.AND)

Comment: так второй словарь изменился. берите теперь из `<переменная с новым словарем>['sample']`

Comment: Честно не понял. Можете пояснить?

Comment: Обновил. Примите ответ, если он верный и помог

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127970/discussion-between-fedor-and-za-ars).